# Is there a way to specify which values file to use in a helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

In one of our helm charts we have a values file per environment e.g.

```
app-helm-chart:
  dev-values.yaml
  test-values.yaml
  Chart.yaml
  templates
    deployment.yaml
    service.yaml
    ingress.yaml
  Readme.md
```

We have packaged up the helm chart using helm package and are then trying to install it from our helm repository.

Is there a way to specify to use the dev-values file from within the package as part of the install command?

Trying to package and version the values and templates all in one place if possible.

Thanks

Comment: [Helm: use packaged values.dev.yaml for install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71341588/helm-use-packaged-values-dev-yaml-for-install) asked a similar question a week ago.  I don't think this is an option in Helm but I don't have an authoritative answer or a workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two answers to this question.

First one, using your current package and repo setup, you would need to download and extract the package then call the values file from the chart folder

```
helm repo add test-repo http://url/to/your repo
helm repo update
helm fetch test-repo/my-chart-name --untar [--version x.x.x]  #This creates a directory called "my-chart-name" in the local directory
helm upgrade --install --atomic --wait ./my-chart-name/ -f ./mychart-name/dev-values.yaml
```

The second, better way, and this was already hinted to by Gaël J is not to include environment-specific values in the chart -- because if you do, each time you change the values or add new values, you'll need to repackage the chart and update the chart repo.

The better way, and the way we do it is to have a separate folder, something like this

```
.
├── charts
│   └── my-chart
│       ├── Chart.lock
│       ├── charts
│       │   └── ingress-nginx-3.35.0.tgz
│       ├── Chart.yaml
│       ├── README.md
│       └── templates
│           ├── deployment.yaml
│           ├── _helpers.tpl
│           ├── ingress.yaml
│           ├── NOTES.txt
│           ├── serviceaccount.yaml
│           └── service.yaml
├── profiles
│   ├── values-preprod.yaml
│   └── values-prod.yaml
```

In this way, I can update the profiles yaml freely and then use the local (or remote) chart -- and the chart contents or version don't need to change whenever I update the values.

```
helm upgrade --install --atomic --wait ./charts/my-chart -f profiles/values-preprod.yaml
```

or

```
helm upgrade --install --atomic --wait test-repo/my-chart -f profiles/values-preprod.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
helm install -f dev-values.yaml ./mychart
```

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/

Comment: Sorry i think i haven't explained myself enough, we have packaged the contents shown above and published it to a helm repo, we then have done a helm repo add and then are trying to install the chart from that repo.

So the values file isnt stored locally it is stored within the helm package which is being hosted on the helm repo.

Comment: Ah, right. I wouldn't package the values of specific environments inside the chart. The chart package should not change if a configuration change.